# Performance Testing Methodology

Tags: performance, testing, performance-testing, database-performance

I'm looking for a "concrete" methodology to individuate performance bottleneck of a service provided through a web application. I'm looking for an holistic approach that includes testing of computer network, database and web applications. 
Suppose that you are in front of a web application that allows you to download pdf files once logged in your company network.
You access to the application with a browser.
The end user requirement is that the web application must allows to download pdf files (with size up to 5MB) in no more than 1 minute.
Some technical details:
- The application consists of a database, a document management system (e.g., Alfresco) and pieces of Java code.
- An user authenticates him/herself by providing username and password to the application, the application on its turn sends them to the LDAP server (the LDAP server is deployed on another physical server). A java serlet does this work and additionally queries the DB to understand the role of the user (a user can be the administrator, a reader, a writer).
- An authenticated user access to a search page, after searching a document the file will be downloaded. The search works in this way: the user fills in some fields (e.g., the name of the document) the field is sent to the document management systems which performs the actual search of the file and returns the results back to the application. 
When the user clicks the download button, the application retrieves the document from the document management system.

The underlying network should be 1GB Eth with some routers/bridges and a load balancer, we have a broad knowledge of network topology.

My question is: if there is a performance bottleneck somewhere (in the network, in the web application, e.g., poor coding) that violates the former requirement (1 second download time) how can we discover it? From which element should we start? For instance trying to understand network performance, then document management systems and at the end the whole system (application, network, database). How should we incrementally increase the number of download request?

I'm looking for a methodology, I've already read

http://www.agileload.com/performance-testing/performance-testing-methodology/test-methodology

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924375.aspx

[What performance testing methodology are you using for your webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686694/what-performance-testing-methodology-are-you-using-for-your-webapps)

All them contain nice suggestions, but I want a more practical methodology with reference to testing of web application. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is it one minute or one second for a 5MB file?  Can you post a diagram
of how the various pieces are connected?

There is a way to determine how the network latency and application processing contribute towards the total response time.

It requires instrumenting the browser and other components that make up the complete system.  I.e. writing code in JavaScript, Java, C/C++, Perl, Python, etc. and embedding it into each of the application component so that components can report events to a central collector.

If instrumentation cannot be easily added to the components, then the other alternative to insert event collecting proxies between components and then have them report events to a central collector. You can determine and factor out delays due to proxies by running few tests with and without proxies in the path.

Once the events arrive at the central collector, one can get good visibility into how the response time is made up.